# Import p12 certificate with full access to private key for my application (OS X)

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, certificate, keychain

I'm accessing the https webserver with certificate authentication from mac app, so I need to handle authentication and provide my certificate (URLSession -> NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate -> call SecPKCS12Import and extract identity from imported certificate -> create NSURLCredential from identity and provide it in completionHandler to the server) .

But after each https request the dialog box "MYAPP wants to sign using "privateKey" in your keychain" is displayed:

[image]

I want to avoid this message. My app is signed correctly. I think I need to set access for the certificate while importing (full access for my app), I'm trying to do it using SecAccessCreate and SecPKCS12Import options:

```
func extractIdentity(certData:NSData, certPassword:String) -> IdentityAndTrust {

        var identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust!
        var securityError:OSStatus = errSecSuccess

        var items:CFArray?
        //let certOptions:CFDictionary = [ kSecImportExportPassphrase.takeRetainedValue() as String: certPassword ];

        let index: CFIndex = 2

        let passwordKey = kSecImportExportPassphrase as String;
        let passwordValue: CFString = "PASSWORD";

        let accessKey = kSecImportExportAccess as String;
        var access:SecAccessRef? = nil;
        SecAccessCreate("CERTIFICATE_NAME", nil, &access);

        var keys = [unsafeAddressOf(accessKey), unsafeAddressOf(passwordKey)]
        var values = [unsafeAddressOf(access!), unsafeAddressOf(passwordValue)]

        var keyCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
        var valueCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks

        let options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &keys, &values, index, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)

        // import certificate to read its entries
        securityError = SecPKCS12Import(certData, options, &items);

        if securityError == errSecSuccess {

            let certItems:CFArray = items as CFArray!;
            let certItemsArray:Array = certItems as Array
            let dict:AnyObject? = certItemsArray.first;

            if let certEntry:Dictionary = dict as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                // grab the identity
                let identityPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["identity"];
                let secIdentityRef:SecIdentityRef = identityPointer as! SecIdentityRef!;

                // grab the trust
                let trustPointer:AnyObject? = certEntry["trust"];
                let trustRef:SecTrustRef = trustPointer as! SecTrustRef;

                // grab the certificate chain
                var certRef:SecCertificate?
                SecIdentityCopyCertificate(secIdentityRef, &certRef);
                let certArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
                certArray.addObject(certRef as SecCertificateRef!);

                identityAndTrust = IdentityAndTrust(identityRef: secIdentityRef, trust: trustRef, certArray: certArray);
            }
        }

        return identityAndTrust;
    }
```

Anyway it doesn't work. How can I avoid this dialog box?

This thread [How do I add authorizations to code sign an app from new keychain without any human interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864770/how-do-i-add-authorizations-to-code-sign-an-app-from-new-keychain-without-any-hu) is related to importing the certificate using "security" command, and suggestion was to use -A or -T flags while importing the certificate, but can I do it programmatically without console commands?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably building and running the application multiple times, which means that the cert was added to the keychain the first time, and the executable that did it was authorized to use the private key. However when you made some changes and rebuilt the project, the executable was replaced and the new executable doesn't have access to the private key (this is also an issue when your users have to update your software or reinstall for any reason).

What I found I had to do was remove the cert from the keychain after I used it, and re-add it before every use. However I've read that you can grant permission to an app identifier so that may work in your case too.

I have a code sample in my question's answer: [How do I kill the popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602553/how-do-i-kill-the-popup/)