# How do I kill the popup?

Tags: c++, macos, libcurl

If you edit the following code to have valid certificate paths and a url that requires client certificates and then compile it with `clang++ -lcurl curl.cpp` on OS X (I'm using El Cap, but I think Mavericks or later behave the same way), and run the executable, you get a popup (shown below) from OS X asking if you want to allow the executable to use a private key in your keychain. This is annoying to users that know what's going on (internally curl on OS X uses the OS X security framework to load the client cert) but it's frightening for users who don't know what's happening because they think that the program is trying to access a private key in their keychain (as an aside this is an example of terrible UX from Apple as the popup message is a complete red herring).

The curl command line tool doesn't produce a popup, so either there is a lower level API I could use or it's because the executable is signed. The real program I'm trying to add this feature to is often distributed as source code so signing the executable isn't an ideal approach, as I can't distribute the signing keys or they'll be revoked. Does anyone know how I can prevent the popup programmatically?

[image: Popup with warning text: a wants to sign using key "privateKey" in your keychain. The authenticity of "a" cannot be verified. Do you want to allow access to this item? and buttons for Allow, Deny, and Always Allow]

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static size_t receiveResponseBytes(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userData) {
  string *responseData = (string *) userData;
  responseData->append((const char *) buffer, size * nmemb);
  return size * nmemb;
}

void prepareCurlPOST(CURL *curl, string &bodyJsonString, string *responseData, struct curl_slist **chunk) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.dev/v1/check.json");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 0);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, bodyJsonString.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, bodyJsonString.length());
  *chunk = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: application/json");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, *chunk);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "/path/to/client_cert.p12");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "P12");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "1234");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, receiveResponseBytes);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, responseData);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/ca.crt");
}

int main(){
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
  struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
  string responseData;
  long responseCode;
  string bodyJsonString = "{\"version\": 1}";
  prepareCurlPOST(curl, bodyJsonString, &responseData, &chunk);
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",curl_easy_strerror(curl_easy_perform(curl)));
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode);
  if (responseCode != 200) {
    fprintf(stderr, "HTTP %d %s\n", (int) responseCode, responseData.c_str());
  }
  curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem (thanks to the Phusion folks for letting me tinker on this):

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>

using namespace std;

const char* cert_label = "Name of the certificate as it appears in keychain access";
const char* domain = "https://example.dev/v1/check.json";
const char* ca_path = "/path/to/ca.crt";
const char* cert_path = "/path/to/client_cert.p12";
const char* cert_pw = "1234";

static OSStatus LookupKeychainItem(const char *label,
                                   SecIdentityRef *out_cert_and_key)
{
  OSStatus status = errSecItemNotFound;

  if(kSecClassIdentity != NULL) {
    CFTypeRef keys[4];
    CFTypeRef values[4];
    CFDictionaryRef query_dict;
    CFStringRef label_cf = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, label,
                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    /* Set up our search criteria and expected results: */
    values[0] = kSecClassIdentity; /* we want a certificate and a key */
    keys[0] = kSecClass;
    values[1] = kCFBooleanTrue;    /* we need a reference */
    keys[1] = kSecReturnRef;
    values[2] = kSecMatchLimitOne; /* one is enough, thanks */
    keys[2] = kSecMatchLimit;
    /* identity searches need a SecPolicyRef in order to work */
    values[3] = SecPolicyCreateSSL(false, label_cf);
    keys[3] = kSecMatchPolicy;
    query_dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)keys,
                                    (const void **)values, 4L,
                                    &kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                    &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFRelease(values[3]);
    CFRelease(label_cf);

    /* Do we have a match? */
    status = SecItemCopyMatching(query_dict, (CFTypeRef *)out_cert_and_key);
    CFRelease(query_dict);
  }

  return status;
}

SecAccessRef createAccess()
{
  SecAccessRef access=NULL;
  if (SecAccessCreate(CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, cert_label, kCFStringEncodingUTF8), NULL, &access)){
    printf("SecAccessCreate failed\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  return access;
}

static OSStatus CopyIdentityFromPKCS12File(const char *cPath,
                                           const char *cPassword,
                                           SecIdentityRef *out_cert_and_key)
{
  OSStatus status = errSecItemNotFound;
  CFURLRef pkcs_url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(NULL,
                                                              (const UInt8 *)cPath, strlen(cPath), false);
  CFStringRef password = cPassword ? CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL,
                                                               cPassword, kCFStringEncodingUTF8) : NULL;
  CFDataRef pkcs_data = NULL;

  if(CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource(NULL, pkcs_url, &pkcs_data,
                                              NULL, NULL, &status)) {
    SecAccessRef access = createAccess();
    const void *cKeys[] = {kSecImportExportPassphrase,kSecImportExportAccess};
    //kSecTrustSettingsKeyUseAny
    const void *cValues[] = {password,access};
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, cKeys, cValues,
                                                 2L, NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = NULL;

    /* Here we go: */
    status = SecPKCS12Import(pkcs_data, options, &items);

    if(items)
      CFRelease(items);
    CFRelease(options);
    CFRelease(pkcs_data);
  }

  if(password)
    CFRelease(password);
  CFRelease(pkcs_url);
  return status;
}

static size_t receiveResponseBytes(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userData) {
  string *responseData = (string *) userData;
  responseData->append((const char *) buffer, size * nmemb);
  return size * nmemb;
}

void prepareCurlPOST(CURL *curl, string &bodyJsonString, string *responseData, struct curl_slist **chunk) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, domain);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 0);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, bodyJsonString.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, bodyJsonString.length());
  *chunk = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: application/json");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, *chunk);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, cert_label);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, receiveResponseBytes);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, responseData);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ca_path);
}

void killKey(){
    SecIdentityRef id = NULL;
    if (LookupKeychainItem(cert_label,&id) != errSecItemNotFound){

        CFArrayRef itemList = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)&id, 1, NULL);
        const void *keys2[]   = { kSecClass,  kSecMatchItemList,  kSecMatchLimit };
        const void *values2[] = { kSecClassIdentity, itemList, kSecMatchLimitAll };

        CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys2, values2, 3, NULL, NULL);
        OSStatus oserr = SecItemDelete(dict);
        if (oserr) {
            CFStringRef str = SecCopyErrorMessageString(oserr, NULL);
            printf("Removing Passenger Cert from keychain failed: %s Please remove the private key from the certificate labeled %s in your keychain.", CFStringGetCStringPtr(str,kCFStringEncodingUTF8), cert_label);
            CFRelease(str);
        }
        CFRelease(dict);
        CFRelease(itemList);

    }
}

void preAuthKey(){
  SecIdentityRef id = NULL;
  if(LookupKeychainItem(cert_label,&id) == errSecItemNotFound){
    OSStatus status = SecKeychainSetUserInteractionAllowed(false);
    if(status != errSecSuccess){
      printf("%s\n",CFStringGetCStringPtr(SecCopyErrorMessageString(status,NULL),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    }
    CopyIdentityFromPKCS12File("/path/to/client_cert.p12","1234",&id);
    status = SecKeychainSetUserInteractionAllowed(true);
    if(status != errSecSuccess){
      printf("%s\n",CFStringGetCStringPtr(SecCopyErrorMessageString(status,NULL),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  preAuthKey();
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
  struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
  string responseData;
  long responseCode;
  string bodyJsonString = "{\"version\": 1}";
  prepareCurlPOST(curl, bodyJsonString, &responseData, &chunk);
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",curl_easy_strerror(curl_easy_perform(curl)));
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode);
  if (responseCode != 200) {
    fprintf(stderr, "HTTP %d %s\n", (int) responseCode, responseData.c_str());
  }
  curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  killKey();
}
```